# gRPC Connection Cancelled with "Multiplexer Hanging Up" Error in PyFlink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have tried to implement the Python datastream example present in the Flink Documentation. Upon implementing it, I get the following error.
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner self.run() File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) File "/Users/shashikanth/Downloads/flink-1.17.2/pyflink_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 669, in <lambda> target=lambda: self._read_inputs(elements_iterator), File "/Users/shashikanth/Downloads/flink-1.17.2/pyflink_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 652, in _read_inputs for elements in elements_iterator: File "/Users/shashikanth/Downloads/flink-1.17.2/pyflink_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 542, in __next__ return self._next() File "/Users/shashikanth/Downloads/flink-1.17.2/pyflink_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 968, in _next raise self grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.CANCELLED details = "Multiplexer hanging up" debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B::1%5D:50616 {created_time:"2024-03-20T10:56:21.548564+05:30", grpc_status:1, grpc_message:"Multiplexer hanging up"}"`

The versions I am using are:
Mac M2, Flink 1.17 and python 3.9

Has anyone encountered this problem before, or does anyone have suggestions on what might be causing this and how to resolve it? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.